# How can i create this bootstrap grid layout?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-grid

I'm trying to archive this layout on my page(left side of the picture), but I can't make the second element span on both rows. In container 2 I need to insert an image. Also, when I minimize the screen size, to make it a smartphone screen size, the layout needs to look like this(on the right side of the picture).

[layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zvlO.png)

Comment: You definitely have to show your code. We need to see what you made to be able to help you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
I dont know your code but you can try to use row in row
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">1</div>
                <div class="col-12">2</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
            3
          </div>
        </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank so much for helping! Sorry for not showing any code, i'm new to this, just trying to learn how to proper create responsive design. I didn't know where to start from with the layout, that's why i didn't show any code. Thank again!

Comment: I'm glad I could be of help ^^ If you are new at coding you can try to watch tutorial videos instead of reading documents at first. Good luck at your coding life :)